# SQL query: sum scores of players

Tags: sql

Given the table `Games`:

| Id | Player1 | Player2 | ScorePlayer1 | ScorePlayer2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cathrine | John | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Bob | Cathrine | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | John | Bob | 3 | 2 |

Which SQL query will output:

| Player | TotalScore |
| --- | --- |
| Cathrine | 6 |
| Bob | 4 |
| John | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

You can agregate and union separately, then aggregate the result:

```
with p as (
    select player1 Player, Sum(ScorePlayer1) TotalScore
    from Games
    group by player1
    union all
    select player2, Sum(ScorePlayer2) 
    from Games
    group by player2
)
select Player, Sum(TotalScore) TotalScore
from p
group by Player
order by TotalScore desc;
```

Comment: Much obliged! It works just as I hoped for. Thank you!